# How can I ensure my Redis and RDS is accessible only for dynamic instances (AWS Autoscaling)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache, aws-security-group, aws-elb

I have hosted my magento2 site in AWS auto-scaling and using Redis/Elasticache, RDS. How I can ensure my Redis and RDS are accessible only from dynamic instances creating in auto-scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Redis/Elasticache, RDS inside a security group and configure its Security Group Inbound rule to only allow the traffic from Security Group of Instances from AWS AutoScaling.

Something like below shown in the picture. Configuring Security Group's inbound rule to allow traffic from different Security Group which will restrict all the other traffic to enter except from the configured Security Group.

[image]

More details can be found below :

[Security Group for ElastiCache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/SecurityGroups.Creating.html)

[RDS Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)